# how to fix on click event. it is not working even the debug is not pointing toward it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

i'm creating a `datatable` for `insert, update`. edit event will fire on the click of  but it is not firing any event on click, even the debug is not pointing toward it on click.

```
function GetLoginData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/LoginMaster/GetLoginData',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            var GetLoginData = result;
            //$('#tblLoginMaster').DataTable.clear();
            //$('#tblLoginMaster').DataTable.destroy();
            //                table.empty();
            if (GetLoginData != '') {
                var str = "";

                $.each(GetLoginData, function (index, obj) {
                    var GetID = obj.Id == null ? "" : obj.Id;
                    var GetName = obj.Name == null ? "" : obj.Name;
                    var GetEmailID = obj.Email == null ? "" : obj.Email;
                    var GetPassword = obj.Password == null ? "" : obj.Password;
                    var GetRole = obj.Role == null ? "" : obj.Role;
```

This is where my `editstyle` class is

```
                    str += "<tr class='EditStyle' data-target='#addUserModal' data-toggle='modal' value='" + GetID +"'>";
                    str += "<td>" + GetID + "</td>";
                    str += "<td>" + GetName + "</td>";
                    str += "<td>" + GetEmailID + "</td>";
                    str += "<td>" + GetPassword + "</td>";
                    str += "<td>" + GetRole + "</td>";
                    str += "</tr>"
                    $('#tblbodyLoginMaster').html(str);
                });
                $('#tblLoginMaster').DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "searching": false,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "sDom": 'lfrtip'
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my `click event`

```
$('tr.EditStyle').on('click', function () {
    if ((this).val() != 0) {
        var rowData = (this).children('td').val();

        $('#id').val(rowData[0]);
        $('#username').val(rowData[1]);
        $('#emailId').val(rowData[2]);
        $('#password').val(rowData[3]);
        $('#role').val(rowData[4]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. When `click` event is firing and when not? Add your `html` code as well.

Comment: Also, where in the entire flow of things you're doing are you binding the click handler for `.EditStyle`? Before or after you add it to the DOM?

Comment: @SandeepNegi : Have you solved the issue or still looking for solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting your click handler doesn't work as your rows do not exist by the time you attempt to listen for clicks. Try to change that, like this:

```
$('#tblLoginMaster').on('click', 'tr.EditStyle', function () {
    ...
});
```

If that solves your problem, you may check out [oficial tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on that topic.

Another thing in your code that raises my concern is using jQuery `$.ajax()` method to populate your table and the very method you populate that:

- in order to fetch your data dynamically, you should use DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option and take the advantage of [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc):

```
$('#tblLoginMaster').DataTable({
    ...,
    ajax: {
        url: '/LoginMaster/GetLoginData',
        method: 'GET',
        dataSrc: //here goes json property or the method that retrieves table data out of json response
    }
});
```

- you don't need to cook up table body HTML on your own, you may simply point to corresponding source data properties within [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)/[`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) options, and make use of `createdRow` option to assign necessary row attributes:

```
$('#tblLoginMaster').DataTable({
    ...,
    rowCreated: (tr, _, rowIdx) => $(tr).attr({
        'class':'EditStyle', 
        'data-target': '#addUserModal', 
        'data-toggle': 'modal', 
        'value': rowIdx
    }),
    columns: [
        {data: 'Id', header: 'Id'},
        {data: 'Name', header: 'Name'},
        {data: 'Password', header: 'Password'},
        ...
    ]
});
```

You may be reluctant to do such a global change to your app, but otherwise you may run into different sorts of issues related to AJAX-async nature and deprive yourself of the possibility to use the plethora of DataTables [API methods](https://datatables.net/reference/api) to catch the bugs or enrich your app with new features.

Comment: $('#tblLoginMaster').on('click', 'tr.EditStyle', function () {
    ...
});   - thi S works for me

Comment: @SandeepNegi: So, you're welcome to accept the answer